# How to add scrollability into a Layout consisting of inner layouts

Tags: android, xml

My XML file looks like this.....
Could you please help me how to make it scrollable....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smsImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.32"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
            android:onClick="smsImageHandler"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cameraImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
            android:onClick="cameraImageHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
            android:onClick="searchButtonHandler"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/openWebButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.09"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
            android:onClick="openWebButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="20px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.09"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/callLogButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.17"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
            android:onClick="callLogButtonHandler"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mediaButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
            android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried putting the scroll functionality by wrapping all the layouts inside a main layout and using the scrollview but it showed errors..please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/smsImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.32"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
        android:onClick="smsImageHandler"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cameraImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
        android:onClick="cameraImageHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
        android:onClick="searchButtonHandler"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/openWebButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
        android:onClick="openWebButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="20px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callLogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
        android:onClick="callLogButtonHandler"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mediaButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
</LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove the external LinearLayout as it's useless and it's just making the app slower

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/smsImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="0.32"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
                        android:onClick="smsImageHandler"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cameraImageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="0.40"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
                        android:onClick="cameraImageHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="0.16"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
                        android:onClick="searchButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/openWebButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="0.09"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_blue"
                        android:onClick="openWebButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="20px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="0.09"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/callLogButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.17"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
                        android:onClick="callLogButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/mediaButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_orange"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="317dp"
                    android:layout_height="104dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5px" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.29"
                        android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_green"
                        android:onClick="mediaButtonHandler"
                        android:paddingLeft="10px"
                        android:paddingRight="10px"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is lot of mistake in layout what u want in your layout means horizontal scrolling or vertical scrolling